# sum digits (python simple)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

I wanted to write a program which adds the digits until it becomes a single digit number, here is my code

```
n=int(input(""))
b=10**18
while not 1<=n<=b:
    n=int(input(""))
else: 
    tot=0
    while(n!=0):
        dig=n%10
        tot=tot+dig
        n=n//10
    s=0
    if tot>=10:
           while (tot!=0):
               tot2=tot%10
               s=s+tot2
               tot=tot//10
    else:
               s=tot    
    print(s)
```

I thinked that it works correctly but when I type 88888888888 it gives me 16 as output not 7 ...but every thing   is correct ...How can I fix that?

Comment: How can 7 be the expected result of adding the digits of 88888888888?

Comment: @mkrieger1 He wants to keep adding digits until reaches a one-digit number. In other words, 88888888888->88->16->7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do

`s = n % 9`

Because from math we know that sum of digits of any number and a number itself has the same remainder when divided by 9. The only corner case is when n is divisible 9, in this case, you want s=9.

The final code would be:

```
n=int(input())
b=10**18
while not 1 <= n <= b:
    n=int(input())
if (n%9 == 0):
    s = 9
else:
    s = n % 9
```

Comment: Just for funsies, you can use a tiny tweak to compute this branchlessly (no `if`/`else`): `s = (n - 1) % 9 + 1`. Subtracting `1` before computing `% 9` means you get results cycled one backwards from where they'd have been, with wraparound (so `n % 9 == 0` becomes `(n - 1) % 9 == 8`, while all inputs that wouldn't produce `0` just produce a value one lower), and adding the `1` back in afterwards adjusts it back to the 1-9 range, rather than 0-8. That said, this is "the best solution", but doesn't really help the OP understand what they did wrong with their naïve solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this recursively.

```
def sumDigits(N): return N if N<10 else sumDigits(sum(divmod(N,10)))

sumDigits(88888888888) # 7
```

If you want a mathematical solution:

```
def sumDigits(N): return (N+8)%9+1
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is simple that you don't do enough iterations, as Daniyar Aubekerov commented you need 3 round for 88888888888 (88888888888->88->16->7 ) but you only do 2

one way to solve it is simple factor out the commons parts into their own functions and use them as needed, for example

```
def digits(n):
    "digits of the number n"
    dig = []
    while n>0:
        n,d = divmod(n,10) # this do both n//10 and n%10
        dig.append(d)
    return dig

def sum_digits(n):
    s = sum(digits(n)) #sum add together all the elements in the list
    while s>10:
        s = sum(digits(s))
    return s
```

or even more simple, use a more direct approach to get it, as this is also know as the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of the number

```
def digital_root(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + (n-1)%9
```

and some quick test

```
>>> digits(100)
[0, 0, 1]
>>> digits(88888888888)
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
>>> sum_digits(88888888888)
7
>>> digital_root(88888888888)
7
>>>
```